# Managed Kafka instance | OpenShift Developer Sandbox | Denied Permission /deployments/run-java.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift

I have been following this tutorial on how to install a Managed Kafka instance:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/04/23/connecting-to-your-managed-kafka-instance-from-the-developer-sandbox-for-red-hat-openshift

I attempted to add the container image below from quay.io/repository/rhosak :

**quay.io/rhosak/quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart:latest**

The POD is currently receiving traffic but remains **Pending** and scaled to zero in a light blue colour that can be seen in the Topology under the Developer role.

I can not see the logs but in the events there are several warnings saying that I have permission denied to start the container with **/deployments/run-java.sh**.

I believe that I might have found the troubleshoot in the documentation:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7023937

but I am not aware on how to apply this change in the Containerfile:

```
RUN chmod 755 /opt/mydummy-dir/start_app.sh
```

Perhaps updating the **Deployment Config** might be a possible solution (but please correct me if I am wrong):

spec:
containers:
- name: my-container
image: openshift-registry/my-image:latest
securityContext:
runAsUser: 1000
runAsGroup: 1000
fsGroup: 2000

[image: spec_containers]

Thank you!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

All events :

```
11:28 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Container image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/userid-codeklaudia-dev/quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart@sha256:3ef97108bf097eda4c60a730b7cd08aab6ff28d87049d49045d211f393bbfcdc" already present on machine


11:16 PM
DeploymentDquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart
Scaled down replica set quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf to 1 from 2


11:16 PM
DeploymentDquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart
Scaled up replica set quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf to 2 from 1


10:20 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
(combined from similar events): Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:20:02Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:19 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:19:38Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:19 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:19:27Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:19 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:19:12Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:57Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:41Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:28Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:13Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:01Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Add eth0 [10.131.11.229/23] from openshift-sdn


10:18 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Error: container create failed: time="2023-09-30T21:18:00Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: eaccess /deployments/run-java.sh: **permission denied**"


10:17 PM
DeploymentDquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart
Scaled up replica set quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf to 1


10:17 PM
PodPquarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-jfc5r
Successfully assigned userid-codeklaudia-dev/quarkus-kafka-sb-quickstart-75f4db7fbf-j
```